# generator of lists from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, generator

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
   node    centroid
    1         1
    2         2
    3         4
    5         6
    7         2
    4         1
    8         4
    10        1
```

how can I create a generator of lists by this dataset in a way that nodes with the same centroid are in the same list?
I need to have the result like find-clique return(https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html)

Answer (score 1):

You use `yield` to make generators.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({"node": [random.randint(1, 11) for _ in range(8)],
                   "centroid": [random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(8)]})

def list_gen(df):
  for x in df.centroid.unique():
    yield df[df["centroid"] == x].node.values

[x for x in list_gen(df)]
```

This will give numpy arrays, but you can deconstruct those back into regular `list` simply by passing them to `list`.